# Modifying Realm List tries to recreate linked Objects

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

I have the following (simplified) Realm Models:

```
final class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var identifier: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var programSet: ProgramSet?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identifier"
    }
}

final class ProgramSet: Object {
    @objc dynamic var identifier: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var editorialCategory: EditorialCategory?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identifier"
    }
}
final public class EditorialCategory: Object {
    @objc dynamic var identifier: String = ""
    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identifier"
    }
}

final class Playlist: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var created = Date()

    var items = List<Item>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

When the user adds an item to a playlist, I try to append the ItemModel to the Playlist.items List:

```
try realm.write {
    playlistToModify.items.append(item)
}
```

My problem is that it's possible for Items to share the same EditorialCategory, so it may already be in the database. When I add other items via the Realm.add(_:update:) method, Realm won't try to recreate the linked objects if one with the same primary key exists.

The List.append(_:) method seems to force recreating the linked objects of an ItemModel when called. The app crashes in the following line from `object_accessor.hpp`:

```
throw std::logic_error(util::format("
Attempting to create an object of type '%1' with an existing primary key value '%2'.", 
object_schema.name, ctx.print(*primary_value)));
```

Stacktrace:

[image]

The object_schema.name is "EditorialCategoryModel", which is linked in ProgramSetModel, which itself is linked from ItemModel.

Is there a way to avoid this error and append the item to the list without Realm attempting to re-create every linked object? Thanks!

Comment: When creating simplified models for reproducing your error, please make sure you create __valid__ examples. Realm requires model __classes__, so your `struct` models are obviously non-valid. Moreover, none of the properties are marked `dynamic` making your models unusable for persisting in Realm. Also, please provide more context, especially what's `item.managedObject()`, since there's no `managedObject()` function declared in your current code at all. In general, your error can be solved by setting the `update` input parameter to `true` when calling `realm.add`.

Comment: I've adjusted the example. `item.managedObject()` is just another representation - the real object that is written to Realm while Item is what we use for convenience reasons throughout our app. But that's not important for this issue. My problem is, that `append()` behaves differently from `add()` in that it adds linked objects with `update = false`

Comment: `item` an object of type `ItemModel` that is not-yet persisted in Realm, right?

Comment: Yes, though I've tried to add the item beforehand via                         'realm.add(item, update: true)' and still get the same error, only in that case the 'object-schema.name' is 'Item', so it looks like it attempts to create the same item object again

Comment: Are you using `Swift4`? I cannot reproduce your error in `Swift3`. You can find the code I was using for testing [here](https://gist.github.com/davidpasztor/1d49c1b23780a01a4305da25a48ebc70).

Comment: I am using Swift4 but have found my error now. I was calling `realm.add()` with `item.managedObject()` and `append(item.managedObject())` right afterwards, which returns a newly created object. After binding item.managedObject() to a temporary variable and passing that variable, everything works as expected. Thanks for helping me debug!